# Call DLL with dictionaries in C++ Builder from C#

Tags: dictionary, generics, c++builder

I have to create a DLL in C++ Builder XE7 or later, for a colleague who needs to call it from C#, by passing a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

I looked around the web for some ideas on the C++ Builder side. But found nothing.
Specifically, I need help on the C++ Builder side, in order to accept the dictionary and extract values by key, including primitives, strings, and objects of a generic class known in both C# and C++.

Any hints or pointers on handling the type conversions and memory management for this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot of detail you're missing out of your question - for example, _why_ are you doing this in the first place? How will data be passed? What are the exact kinds of `Object` being stored in the dictionary? What should happen if someone passes a`Dictionary<String,FileStream>`? How do you want to marshal: is passing data-by-value (i.e. serialization) okay or do you want pass-data-by-ref semantics (like COM)? And by "C++" do you _really_ mean C++/CLI (or C++/CX) - or P/Invoke? Why not use WinRT types? What kind of ABI stability do you need? Etc etc...

Comment: @Giovanni Short answer - what you are attempting is not possible. C++ cannot directly access a C# `Dictionary`, it is simply not an interop-safe type to use across language boundaries, and `Dictionary` can't be exposed to C++ via COM, either.  To make this work, you are going to have to hide the `Dictionary` behind a C-compatible or COM-compatible API for the C++ code to use.

Comment: @Dai the question is clearly about C++Builder, not Visual Studio.  There is no C++/CLI or C++/CX in C++Builder, so the DLL would have to be accessed through PInvoke or COM only.

Comment: @RemyLebeau [C++Builder supports WinRT just fine](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/learn-how-to-use-winrt-in-your-native-windows-delphi-and-c-builder-apps/utilising-winrt-in-your-delphi-c-builder-applications/)

Comment: @Dai Modern versions of C++Builder can use WinRT, but WinRT didn't exist yet when XE7 was released (2014), which is what you asked for.